# Move to SD Card

Tags: android, sd-card

I've been following the post:
http://tut7.com/2010/06/15/quick-tip-enabling-the-android-%E2%80%9Cmove-to-sd-card%E2%80%9D-feature/comment-page-1/#comment-6766
(even tried to post a comment but it's been awaiting moderation forever)...

I'm trying to target Android 1.6-2.2 OSs and after applying your Build Target I get the following warnings:

> Attribute minSdkVersion (4) is lower than the project target API level (8) AndroidManifest.xml /CueBrain line 1 Android ADT Problem

And also, trying to launch my app in the 1.6 emulator it just ignores it and runs the 2.2 emulator.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok um it seems it works on 1.6, it's just the debugger that won't select my 1.6 AVD. I just have to manually install it with "adb install ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you building within Eclipse?  You need to set the target SDK version within the manifest file (like the post you referenced shows), and you also need to set it within the Project settings in Eclipse.

1. On the main menu, go to Project --> Properties
2. Select the Android page
3. Check the box next to the target SDK you would like to build against

You should see the correct Android version in the Package Explorer as library.  Mine is listed as "Android2.2" beneath the "src" and "gen" folders.

Comment: Yup I got that thanks. Why is it giving me warnings? What is the different between sdk min version and target version?

Comment: sdk min is the lowest version of the OS that your application can run on.  The target version is the SDK that you compile against.  Your original error was telling you that you were trying to compile against a version that might have functions not available in the earlier version that your app said it could run on.

Comment: That sounds rather dangerous. How do I know if I'm using functions that are not supported by 1.6? Should I just leave as such and hope QA finds any problems?